# How To Get The Parent value from Json for this select2

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jquery-select2

```js
var preload_data = [{
  "id": 2049,
  "text": "style",
  "children": [{
    "id": "6906957ed912c883",
    "text": "Country"
  }, {
    "id": "d239d844608fdbcf",
    "text": "Christmas"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 0,
  "text": "unassigned",
  "children": [{
    "id": "52d8e1e8d419bb61",
    "text": "Punk"
  }, {
    "id": "88b9826121aeb89b",
    "text": "Upbeat"
  }, {
    "id": "8485e6dd8e33fc50",
    "text": "test arda"
  }, {
    "id": "da9fa55495a4a463",
    "text": "test1"
  }, {
    "id": "feb1177719f4b5a4",
    "text": "test arda 3"
  }, {
    "id": "64a2ae4ec2c0a1ef",
    "text": "Feel Good"
  }, {
    "id": "2512f7946f660dc5",
    "text": "Happy"
  }, {
    "id": "b1e7203207bd068f",
    "text": "Love"
  }, {
    "id": "fb3a42b8abbf975a",
    "text": "Reminiscent"
  }, {
    "id": "56d60aed1278c5a0",
    "text": "Indie"
  }, {
    "id": "5733de46970ac503",
    "text": "Rock"
  }, {
    "id": "801c33b478d1d5be",
    "text": "Singer Songwriter"
  }, {
    "id": "ee4c6f5c12782bb9",
    "text": "World"
  }, {
    "id": "4605140218eb9e52",
    "text": "Reality"
  }, {
    "id": "92934140c305706e",
    "text": "Pop"
  }, {
    "id": "f40f55db44dc0846",
    "text": "Acoustic"
  }, {
    "id": "07b3c4640e84bfeb",
    "text": "Folk"
  }]
}]
```

and I want the output for dropdown list
Style:Christmas for example
this is the select2 code

```
 $("#hidStyles").select2({
        containerCssClass: 'styleContainer',
        data: preload_data,
        width: '100%',
        allowClear: true,
        multiple: true,
        dropdownCssClass: 'select2-hidden',
        placeholder: 'Please enter the name of style here to assign it to this album',
        formatSelection: format1,
        escapeMarkup : function(m) { return m;},
        formatSearching: null
        //formatSelection : format
    });
```

and this is How I format the Json :

```
 function format1(item) {
        opt = $("#hidStyles").find(':selected');
        sel = opt.text;
        //og = opt.closest(".select2-results-dept-0").attr(".select2-result-label");
        ogx = opt.text.data.text;
        return ogx + ':' + item.text;
    }
```

how can I get the value so that it's like style : christmas

https://jsfiddle.net/jna7ft1c/3/

I am sorry the jsfiddle I am not familiar with for making the front end, but mostly the code is like written there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jna7ft1c/3/

this is the jsfiddle, I dont familiar with js I am a newbie actually on frontend, pls help